# How to store the value of a unicode source column greater than 16000 characters in a dedicated SQL pool table

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

There is a unicode source column that is variable in column length since it contains the body of a news article. Therefore, there is no limit to the length of this column. In order to utilize this information, I need to load it into a hash distribution type synapse table. The MAX data length cannot be set on a column of an nvarchar datatype in a hash distributed table. Is there a way to accomplish my requirements now?

Comment: In other words, you have a blob that shouldn't be stored in the database in the first place. `MAX` doesn't mean `don't care about the size` it means the data needs special treatment, storage outside a table's data pages and won't be used in queries as-is.  At the very least you'd need a full text search index to use a news article in any way.  `In order to utilize this information, I need to load it into a hash distribution type synapse table` why?

Comment: `accomplish my requirements now` what *are* the requirement? You asked about problems with an assumed solution, not about the actual problem. Did you assume hash distribution would make an inefficient query run faster? Using the *proper* query or indexes would be faster without requiring distributed storage. A data warehouse is *not* used to search into blobs, that's what search engines are for

Comment: This information is used to determine the positive/negative sentiment score and identify people, events, organizations, and geographical names associated with an article. Our notebooks on Azure Databricks read this information and produce the output listed above. Would it be possible for you to suggest/advise what is the best approach here so our notebooks can access this information? Would it be better to leave them in a blob and have notebooks access the blob rather than the synapses?

Comment: In order to utilize this information, I need to load it into a hash distribution type synapse table? Why

Sorry, I didn't make it clear. We already have a hash distributed table on synapse which currently is just storing headline & first two lines of an article body. So to best calculate the sentiment score we need the complete body text

Comment: You can use the VARCHAR(MAX) data type instead of NVARCHAR(MAX)The VARCHAR(MAX) data type can store up to 2^31-1 bytes of data,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the **MAX** data length on a column of an **NVARCHAR** datatype in a hash-distributed table.

One method to specify the maximum data length for a column of type **NVARCHAR** in a hash-distributed table is to use the **NVARCHAR(MAX)** data type.

This data type can accommodate Unicode string data of up to 2 GB in size.

If the column has any constraint, such as a default or check constraint, you will need to drop the constraint from the column before changing its size. After altering the column size, you can add the constraint back to the column using the following steps:

```
-- Drop the constraint 
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;

-- Alter the column size 
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN table_column NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Add the constraint 
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name DEFAULT ('') FOR table_column;
```

I have tried the below example:

```
CREATE TABLE NewsArticle (
    ArticleID INT ,
    Headline NVARCHAR(100),
    Body1 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body2 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body3 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body4 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body5 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body6 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body7 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body8 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body9 NVARCHAR(4000),
    Body10 NVARCHAR(4000)
)
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH(ArticleID)
);
```

In the above code, you can split the body of the news article into multiple columns and distribute them across the hash distribution. In this way, you can still store the complete body text while utilizing the hash distribution feature.

**Results:**

[image]